# Need to integrate two tables from same excel sheet into one R dataset

Tags: r

I'm dealing with an automatic excel export that has info about the data being exported before the actual data, so that it reads (in excel for ease of copy-paste, although I'm largely using a csv derivative)

```
> Site ID:  Site ID uninitialized                                        
>                    Serial Number: ####    
> TMI Serial Number:    ####-#-#####     
> SW Version:   Comm. 003.003.001 2015-05-27 15:51:17 buildmgr
>OrganType: [some text]
>OrganID:   [random string]                                          
>                    Session Date: 2015-10-21   Session Time: 08:45:18                  
> Date      Time        Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4    Var5
>                       Time    L/min   L/min   L/min   mmHg
> 10/21/2015    8:47:26 --- --- --- --- 0
> 10/21/2015    8:49:26 --- --- --- --- 0
> 10/21/2015    9:33:26 --- --- --- --- 0
> 10/21/2015    9:35:26 --- --- --- --- 0
> 10/21/2015    9:37:26 --- --- --- --- 0
> 10/21/2015    9:39:26 --- 1.46    0.97    1.53    13
```

with the dashed indicating missing data. I can't for the life of me figure out how to make R understand what's going on. Ideally, I'd want the header data integrated into the table of data as variables so that multiple of these files can be merged at a later date for a master list. Do I need to modify it by hand in excel, or is there some bit of R syntax I can use?

Comment: How many files are you talking about? Automatically processing that file would be time consuming because the format is all over the place (I would also use python instead to pre-process the text files and transform them in to proper CSVs), it could only be justified if you have many files. You are probably better off fixing it in excel in a table format (which includes the data of the header as columns, I don't think you want variables in this case). With some excel skills you could create some sort of template that helps you automatizing the task.

Comment: @Scott Do your header data always occupy the same number of rows?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the package XLConnect to read in the Excel file you can specify at which row you start and end to read the worksheet. You can then make the first data.frame the header and the second the "real" data.frame. After that you create new columns in the data.frame to incorporate the data you have from the header.

If the layout changes you might need a different approach. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use regular expressions to parse the header, if the headers are consistent.  Suppose your data is in a file called `testdata.csv`:

```
writeLines(text="Site ID:  Site ID uninitialized                                        
                    Serial Number: ####    
 TMI Serial Number:    ####-#-#####     
 SW Version:   Comm. 003.003.001 2015-05-27 15:51:17 buildmgr
OrganType: [some text]
OrganID:   [random string]                                          
                    Session Date: 2015-10-21   Session Time: 08:45:18                  
 Date      Time        Var1    Var2    Var3    Var4    Var5
                       Time    L/min   L/min   L/min   mmHg
 10/21/2015    8:47:26 --- --- --- --- 0
 10/21/2015    8:49:26 --- --- --- --- 0
 10/21/2015    9:33:26 --- --- --- --- 0
 10/21/2015    9:35:26 --- --- --- --- 0
 10/21/2015    9:37:26 --- --- --- --- 0
 10/21/2015    9:39:26 --- 1.46    0.97    1.53    13",
    con="testdata.csv")
```

An example of how to parse the header:

```
library(stringr)
header <- readLines("testdata.csv", n=7)
headers <- lapply(header[1:6], str_match, "(^.*?):(.*)")
date <- c(field="Date", 
    value=str_match(header[7], "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}"))
time <- c(field="Time", 
    value=str_match(header[7], "[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}"))
d <- do.call(rbind, 
    lapply(headers, function(x) c(str_trim(x[2]), str_trim(x[3]))))
d <- rbind(d, date, time)
d <- data.frame(d, row.names=seq_len(nrow(d)))
```

Output:

```
> d
              field                                          value
1           Site ID                          Site ID uninitialized
2     Serial Number                                           ####
3 TMI Serial Number                                   ####-#-#####
4        SW Version Comm. 003.003.001 2015-05-27 15:51:17 buildmgr
5         OrganType                                    [some text]
6           OrganID                                [random string]
7              Date                                     2015-10-21
8              Time                                       08:45:18
```

You can then join/merge this data into the table of data.